# Multithreading cron jobs in Spring Boot

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, cron

I'm developing a Spring Boot application that looks for given `keywords` in given websites, and scraps the webpages if a match is found. I am writing a cron job to refresh the results every 5 minutes like the following:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* */5 * * * *")
public void fetchLatestResults() throws Exception {
    LOG.debug("Fetching latest results >>>");
    List<Keyword> keywords = keywordService.findOldestSearched10();
    keywordService.updateLastSearchDate(keywords);
    searchResultService.fetchLatestResults(keywords);
    LOG.debug("<<< Latest results fetched");
}
```

The database has 100 `keywords` and in the cron job I'm first listing the oldest 10 keywords for which the results were last fetched. So, for example the first run should use `keywords` with ids 1 to 10 and the second run should use ids 11 to 20 and so on and the 11th run should again use ids 1 to 10 and the process continues.

Now, the problem is that executing the search takes much longer than 5 minutes. So, eventhough I've set the cron job to run every 5 minutes, the second run doesn't take place until the first is completed. As a result, completing the search is taking hours. How can I make this process multithreaded so that multiple instances of the cron job can be run simultaneously since they are operating on different list of `keywords`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you make execution of your cron job asynchronous.

Create `executor` class that'll create a new thread to run your cron job:

```
@Component
public class YourCronJobExecutor {

    private int threadsNumber = 10;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsNumber);
    }

    /**
     * Start.
     * @param runnable - runnable instance.
     */
    public void start(Runnable runnable) {
        try {
            executorService.execute(runnable);
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            init();
            executorService.execute(runnable);
        }
    }
}
```

Create a `processor` class that will contain the logic of your cron job:

```
@Component
public class CronJobProcessor {

    //logger
    //autowired beans

    public void executeYouCronJob() {
        LOG.debug("Fetching latest results >>>");
        List<Keyword> keywords = keywordService.findOldestSearched10();
        keywordService.updateLastSearchDate(keywords);
        searchResultService.fetchLatestResults(keywords);
        LOG.debug("<<< Latest results fetched");
    }
}
```

And finally, your cron job class will look like this:

```
@Component
public class YourCronJobClass {

    private final YourCronJobExecutor yourCronJobExecutor;

    private final CronJobProcessor cronJobProcessor;

    @Autowired
    public PopulateCourseStateController(YourCronJobExecutor yourCronJobExecutor,
                                         CronJobProcessor cronJobProcessor) {
        this.yourCronJobExecutor = yourCronJobExecutor;
        this.cronJobProcessor = cronJobProcessor;
    }   

    @Scheduled(cron = "* */5 * * * *")
    public void fetchLatestResults() throws Exception {
        yourCronJobExecutor.start(cronJobProcessor::executeYouCronJob);
    }
}
```

This way execution of your cron job will take couple of milliseconds, and a separate thread, that'll actually be performing the job will run as long as it needs to.

But perhaps, you'd want to execute search of every keyword in a separate thread, but that's a bit of a different story.

Comment: This works perfectly and has improved the performance. Thanks.